# Windows 8: Switch between windows of current application

Tags: windows-8

If I have, for example, multiple instances of Firefox running then this command would switch between my different Firefox windows.

Would be analogue of Alt-` in Ubuntu.

Comment: Also check out http://superuser.com/a/440026/23133