# Easy way to switch between two windows of the same app in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, alt-tab

I am looking for a way to switch between two open windows of the same app with a key shortcut, I have found this https://neosmart.net/EasySwitch/ but it is not open source and I don't trust it even works. Does anyone has an alternative ? This is OOTB in Unity and Mac OS it is absurd that Windows doesn't have it.

Some time ago a Microsoft employee made this tool : https://switcher.en.softonic.com/ not sure what is the official website, it is GREAT but works only on Windows 7 and doesnt work on 10, also not open source.

The closest thing I have found that is open source is this one https://github.com/JochenBaier/fastwindowswitcher but is less then ideal.

is there an alternative ?

Comment: alt+tab switches between ALL windows of ALL applications.

in Mac OS (Cmd+Tab) and Linux (Alt+Tab) it works the same, however both Mac OS and Ubuntu Unity have a "switch between Windows in the same app" which is ALT+ ` or CMD + ` respectively, this doesnt seems to exist in Windows.

Comment: I find if you hold Alt and just quickly tap Tab it will switch back and forth between the two most recently focussed windows regardless of how many other windows are open. It doesn't cycle through all windows, only back and forth between two of them. It's only if I hold Alt+Tab down for longer that I get the other behaviour.

Comment: Hey @RedGrittyBrick yes but this doesn't help if you have 3 windows :) It kinda helps for 2 :) indeed.

Comment: duplicates: [Shortcut in Windows 7 to switch between same application's windows, like Cmd + ` in OS X](https://superuser.com/q/435602/241386), [What's the windows 10 equivalent of "Command `" on a mac](https://superuser.com/q/1043932/241386), [Windows 8: Switch between windows of current application](https://superuser.com/q/621140/241386)

Comment: You've tried Ctrl + Tab?

Answer (score 44):

You may implement the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> shortcut
yourself using the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will cycle through all the windows of the active
process:

```
!`::
WinGetClass, OldClass, A
WinGet, ActiveProcessName, ProcessName, A
WinGet, WinClassCount, Count, ahk_exe %ActiveProcessName%
IF WinClassCount = 1
    Return
loop, 2 {
  WinSet, Bottom,, A
  WinActivate, ahk_exe %ActiveProcessName%
  WinGetClass, NewClass, A
  if (OldClass <> "CabinetWClass" or NewClass = "CabinetWClass")
    break
}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Copy paste the script didnt work to me. Changed the first line to `!'::`` works

Comment: Is it possible to show a preview of windows, just like alt+tab?

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that it doesn't hide the previous window whenever switching and instead overlays it?

Answer (score 42):

There are three ways for doing this:

1. You can hold  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + Click on the icon of the app in the taskbar
2. Use <kbd>Win</kbd> + position of app on taskbar. For example, if Google Chrome is on third position, do <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to switch between windows of Chrome. Note that this cycles through the different windows, so for opening 4th window you'll have to press 3 four times.
3. **The fastest of all**, Using <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> does exactly what you want. (where n is position of the app on taskbar)

Note that in 2nd and 3rd options if n is specified such that no window of that program is already open, windows will open a new window. This effect can also be acheived by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>, regardless of if windows of that app were already open or not.

Comment: What if n is greater than 9 ?

Comment: @Lucifer, make it lesser than 9 :P. Okay, sorry, there is no real way to do this but you can def rearrange taskbar programs

Comment: This is a good option as does not need to install and add something to OS. Of course with the limitations as mentioned above.

Comment: In my opinion this does not answer the OP well because you need to remember the order of windows in the taskbar and also I would assume that using the mouse is not an option here

Comment: 3rd option is nice, thanks!

Comment: I remapped the third option to `win` + `n` with Microsoft PowerToys. works even faster than ubuntu.

Comment: Can you use PowerToys to actually switch between windows of the same app without catering to their order, as the OP asked and as you can do out of the box e.g. on Ubuntu?

Comment: Second and third options doesn't work on Windows 10 for me (windwos key opens the search bar)

Comment: @JKHA the issue seems limited to your computer only; perhaps you are pressing win and then releasing it, as with sticky keys? If not, are other shortcuts including win key (for eg, Win + I for opening settings) working?

Comment: @SaaranshGarg, I succeed to make it work but it only works with the numbers above the letters, below F1, F2 etc. keys. It does not work with the numeric keypad on the right of my external keyboard.

Answer (score 16):

I've updated the script of harrymc to be executable in AutoHotkey v2:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

!`::{
  OldClass := WinGetClass("A")
  ActiveProcessName := WinGetProcessName("A")
  WinClassCount := WinGetCount("ahk_exe" ActiveProcessName)
  IF WinClassCount = 1
      Return
  loop 2 {
    WinMoveBottom("A")
    WinActivate("ahk_exe" ActiveProcessName)
    NewClass := WinGetClass("A")
    if (OldClass != "CabinetWClass" or NewClass = "CabinetWClass")
      break
  }
}
```

From this it should also be easy to convert the script of EugeneK.

I tried to implement EugeneK's script as well in v2. I'm not sure if it has all the intended features, but it works fine and will be what I'll be using

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

!`::
{
    win_id := WinActive("A")
    win_class := WinGetClass("A")
    active_process_name := WinGetProcessName("A")
    ; We have to be extra careful about explorer.exe since that process is responsible for more than file explorer
    if (active_process_name = "explorer.exe")
        win_list := WinGetList("ahk_exe" active_process_name " ahk_class" win_class)
    else
        win_list := WinGetList("ahk_exe" active_process_name)
    
    ; Calculate index of next window. Since activating a window puts it at the top of the list, we have to take from the bottom.
    next_window_i := win_list.Length
    next_window_id := win_list[next_window_i]
    
    ; Activate the next window and send it to the top.
    WinMoveTop("ahk_id" next_window_id)
    WinActivate("ahk_id" next_window_id)
}
```

In addition: I like having this functionality tied to the key **Alt** + **|**. So, in case you also like this better, change `!'::` to `!|::`.

Comment: Is it possible to have a version which also displays a preview of a window (like Ubuntu) or at least a list

Answer (score 5):

I've modified ahk script in order to have an Ubuntu style switching. Pressing <kbd>`</kbd> while holding an <kbd>alt</kbd> key will cycle through all application windows putting the next one on top rather than sending top window to the bottom. And single <kbd>alt + `</kbd> combinations will cycle between last two windows.

```
!`::
WinGet, ActiveProcessName, ProcessName, A
WinGet, WinClassCount, List, ahk_exe %ActiveProcessName%

if (WinClassCount = 1)
    return

if (NextWindow = "")
    NextWindow := 2

element := % WinClassCount%NextWindow%

WinSet, Top,, ahk_id %element%
WinActivate, ahk_id %element%

NextWindow += 1

if (NextWindow > WinClassCount || !getKeyState("Alt"))
    NextWindow := 2

return
```

Comment: I gave this a try and it has some funny behavior...seems to switch between applications sometimes.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't get any of these answers to do quite what I wanted so I took inspiration from [jenda's solution](https://superuser.com/a/1768047/1858241) and wrote my own AHK V2 script. I really like the way Mac handles this functionality so I tried to mimic that behaviour as closely as possible.

`` alt + ` ``      to cycle forwards through windows

`` alt + shift + ` ``  to cycle backwards through windows

I found that Windows Explorer creates extra processes and windows when pressing alt so I've added `CatchWindowsExplorerErrors = true` to filter out these.

```
#ErrorStdOut
!`::
{
    ;OutputDebug 'cmd+`` `n'
    changeActiveWindow("forward")
}

<+!`::
{
    ;OutputDebug 'cmd+shift+`` `n'
    changeActiveWindow("back")
}

changeActiveWindow(dir)
{
    static windowOrder := []
    static expectedOrder := []
    currentOrder := []
    CatchWindowsExplorerErrors := true ; Windows Explorer creates a number of invisible windows which breaks behavior when using the alt menu. Set this to false to let these errors through.
    debugging := false

    ; Get all windows the same as the active window
    OldClass := WinGetClass("A")
    ActiveProcessName := WinGetProcessName("A")
    WinClassCount := WinGetCount("ahk_exe " ActiveProcessName)
    ActiveId := WinGetID("A")
    OutputDebug 'Current Window:    ' ActiveId '/' OldClass '/' ActiveProcessName '/' WinGetTitle("ahk_id" ActiveId) '`n'
    
    ; If there's only one window, do nothing
    if (WinClassCount = 1)
        Return

    ; Get all windows of the same process
    ids := WinGetList("ahk_exe " ActiveProcessName)
    for SiblingID in ids {
        if (WinGetTitle(SiblingID) != ""){
            if (CatchWindowsExplorerErrors){
                if ( WinGetClass(SiblingID) != "KbxLabelClass" && WinGetTitle(SiblingID) != "Program Manager"){
                    currentOrder.Push(SiblingID)
                }
            } else {
                currentOrder.Push(SiblingID)
            }
        }
    }

    ; Check first run and populate
    if windowOrder.Length = 0 {
        resetWindows()
    }
    printDebugging()

    ; Check if current order and length match expected order and length
    ; If they don't, expected order has changed or a window has been removed or inserted
    if (currentOrder.Length = expectedOrder.Length) {
        Loop currentOrder.Length {
            if (currentOrder[A_Index] != expectedOrder[A_Index]){
                resetWindows()
                break
            }
        }
    } else {
        resetWindows()
    }

    windowOrder := moveToNextIndex(windowOrder, dir)
    changeActiveWindow()
    expectedOrder := updateExpectedOrder(expectedOrder, windowOrder)
    printDebugging()

    OutputDebug '`n'


    ; Functions
    ; Reset the windows to the current state - used if the order doesn't match the expected order e.g. a new window is introduced or the user has clicked and changed order
    resetWindows(){
        OutputDebug 'Restting memory`n'
        windowOrder := currentOrder.Clone()
        expectedOrder := currentOrder.Clone()
        return
    }

    ; Used to update the active window tracked by windowOrder
    changeActiveWindow(){
        WinActivate("ahk_id" windowOrder[1])
        try {
            OutputDebug 'Switching to:    ' WinGetTitle("ahk_id" windowOrder[1]) ' -- ' windowOrder[1] '`n'
        } catch Error as e {
            OutputDebug "An error was thrown!`nSpecifically: " e.Message
            Exit
        }
    }

    ; Print debugging information
    printDebugging(){
        if (debugging){
            OutputDebug '---------------------- currentOrder: ----------------------`n'
            for e in currentOrder {
                OutputDebug WinGetTitle("ahk_id" e) ' -- ' e '`n'
            }
            OutputDebug '---------------------- windowOrder: ----------------------`n'
            for e in windowOrder {
                OutputDebug WinGetTitle("ahk_id" e) ' -- ' e '`n'
            }
            OutputDebug '---------------------- expectedOrder: ----------------------`n'
            for e in expectedOrder {
                OutputDebug WinGetTitle("ahk_id" e) ' -- ' e '`n'
            }
        }
    }
}



getArrayValueIndex(arr, val){
    Loop arr.Length {
        if (arr[A_Index] == val)
            return A_Index
    }
}

moveToNextIndex(arr, dir){
    if (dir == "forward"){
        e := arr[1]
        arr.RemoveAt(1)
        arr.Push(e)
        return arr
    } else if (dir == "back"){
        e := arr[arr.Length]
        arr.RemoveAt(arr.Length)
        arr.InsertAt(1, e)
        return arr
    }
}

moveLastIndexToFirst(arr){
    e := arr[1]
    arr.RemoveAt(1)
    arr.Push(e)
    return arr
}

updateExpectedOrder(eo, wo){
    activeWindowIndex := getArrayValueIndex(eo, wo[1])
    activeWindow := eo[activeWindowIndex]
    eo.RemoveAt(activeWindowIndex)
    eo.InsertAt(1, activeWindow)
    return eo
}
```

Happy to accept PRs if you can spot any optimisations!

https://github.com/BdSteel/AHK-Scripts/blob/main/Window%20Switcher/Window%20Switcher.ahk

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a script using AutoHotkey v2 which does what Ubuntu can do out of the box: switch between windows of the current app by pressing Alt+; (which is what the key in the top left corner types by default on *my* keyboard layout; **you will probably want to adjust for yourself**).
It counts with multiple presses so works even in cases there are multiple windows of the app, not just two. Feel free to use, PRs for improving welcome :-D

https://github.com/jendakol/autohotkey/blob/main/window-switch-multiple.ahk

Current version:

```
!;::
{
    static LastRun := 0
    static QuickPress := 0

    Now := A_TickCount

    if (Now - LastRun < 400)
        QuickPress++
    else
        QuickPress := 0

    OutputDebug '`n`nNow: ' Now ' LastRun: ' LastRun ' QuickPress: ' QuickPress '`n'



    OldClass := WinGetClass("A")
    ActiveProcessName := WinGetProcessName("A")
    WinClassCount := WinGetCount("ahk_exe " ActiveProcessName)
    ActiveId := WinGetID("A")
    OutputDebug 'Current:    ' ActiveId '/' OldClass '/' ActiveProcessName '/' WinGetTitle("ahk_id" ActiveId) "`n"

    if (WinClassCount = 1)
        Return

    ToSkip := QuickPress
    OutputDebug 'Will skip ' ToSkip ' of ' WinClassCount '`n'

    ids := WinGetList("ahk_exe " ActiveProcessName)
    for SiblingId in ids {
        if (WinGetClass("ahk_id" SiblingId) != OldClass)
            continue

        OutputDebug 'Found:      ' SiblingId '/' WinGetClass("ahk_id" SiblingId) '/' WinGetProcessName("ahk_id" SiblingId) '/' WinGetTitle("ahk_id" SiblingId) '`n'

        if (SiblingId != ActiveId && ToSkip-- <=0) {
            OutputDebug 'Switch to:  ' SiblingId '/' WinGetClass("ahk_id" SiblingId) '/' WinGetProcessName("ahk_id" SiblingId) '/' WinGetTitle("ahk_id" SiblingId) '`n'
            WinActivate("ahk_id" SiblingId)
            break
        }
    }


    LastRun := A_TickCount
}
```

Comment: Is it very stable to use on Windows 11?

Comment: This is the only one that worked as expected. You should paste the code here and add instructions on modifying the key to make it work with the backtick.

Comment: @matt I use it quite often. It seems stable, yes :)

Comment: @vega Thanks! I did post the repo link instead intentionally so anyone can get the most updated version every time I commit it ;-)

Comment: @jenda yes this is true, however on SE, links to answers are not considered answers, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer. You'd be surprised, I've often been helped by 10 year old answers with code where the links didn't work anymore. I think this is why SE asks for code instead of links. But you are free to link to your repo of course. Cheers.

Comment: @vega I know the reason but... OK, let me add current version and keep the repo link so everyone is happy :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly (Autohotkey v2)

```
; Shift+Capslock toggles between windows of active app (eg. different firefox windows)
+Capslock::
{
    ActiveApp := WinGetProcessName("A")
    WinActivateBottom("ahk_exe " . ActiveApp)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Windows' native Alt+Tab switcher but with only windows from one application]

I wanted a nice <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> window switching experience, and I thought of a way to do it using the actual <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> UI, no mimicry required.

This script listens for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and converts it to an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> after filtering the windows seen by the task switcher, by setting an attribute on the windows. When you release <kbd>Alt</kbd>, it unfilters the windows by removing the attribute.

You can use <kbd>`</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> while <kbd>Alt</kbd> is held to cycle the list, and you can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to cycle backwards, including when opening the switcher.

Limitations:

- Windows are hidden from the task bar as well, which can be distracting,
  especially with taskbar button labels enabled, as it animates the taskbar buttons collapsing and expanding.
  Windows has a setting to disable taskbar animation, but it doesn't seem to work in Windows 11.
- Some windows are not hidden from the task switcher, such as the Task Manager, due to permission errors.

  - Running as administrator fixes this.
- UWP windows, such as Windows's Settings app, are not filtered out either. They don't play well with any of the methods I've tried.
- There may be side effects on the windows that get hidden, since it temporarily changes their window type, essentially. If something goes wrong, windows may be left excluded from the task bar and task switcher, and without minimize or maximize buttons. I've only seen this happen once, and it may have been due to a work-in-progress version of the script.

I don't use UWP apps much, so this is good enough for me, but I would love it if someone found a solution for hiding UWP windows.

Usage:

- Install [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) v2
- Save script as `window-switcher.ahk` or similar
- Double click the new file to run it once.
- To run at startup with administrator privileges:

  - Open Task Scheduler
  - Action > Create Task...
  - Check "Run with highest privileges" in "Security options" in General tab
  - In Triggers tab, click "New..." and set the type to "At log on"
  - For the Action, you can browse for the script. (You may want to move it somewhere where you'd like to keep it long term first, since it will use the file path to locate the script.)

```
; Requires AutoHotkey v2

;--------------------------------------------------------
; Alt+` to switch between windows of the same application
;--------------------------------------------------------

; This script piggybacks on the built-in Alt+Tab window switcher,
; filtering it to show only windows from the same process as the active window.
; It listens for Alt+` and Alt+Shift+` and converts them to Alt+Tab and Alt+Shift+Tab, respectively,
; after hiding windows from the task switcher by setting their WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style,
; and then unhiding them after the switcher is closed.
; Pressing ` again while holding Alt will tab through the windows of the same application,
; and Shift+` will tab through them in reverse.
; Tab or Shift+Tab also works (automatically, since that's what the switcher normally uses.)

; Limitations:
; - Windows are hidden from the task bar as well, which can be distracting,
;   especially with taskbar button labels enabled, as it animates the taskbar buttons collapsing and expanding.
; - Some windows are not hidden from the task switcher, such as the Task Manager, due to permission errors.
;   - Running as administrator fixes this.
; - UWP windows, such as Windows's Settings app, are not filtered out either.
;   - They don't play well with any of the methods I've tried.
; - There may be side effects on the windows that get hidden, since it changes their window type, essentially, temporarily.
;   - I now have seen it leave File Explorer with no minimize or maximize buttons, stuck on a tool window style,
;     and permanently excluded from the task bar and task switcher.
;     (This may have only been due to a work-in-progress version of this script, or it may be a real issue.)
;     I didn't see this before adding removal of WS_EX_APPWINDOW, so that may be the cause (if it's not a fluke.)
;     Actually it might not be the removal of WS_EX_APPWINDOW, but the code supporting that,
;     which allows for changes to other styles while hidden. If I change that, it might be fine.
;     I've changed it to restore all styles for now, but I don't know if that's even related.

; TODO: remove windows from task switcher only, and not the task bar.
; Adding WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW is much faster than WinHide/WinShow (it makes the actual interaction instantaneous!),
; but it still causes distracting animation in the taskbar, particularly when taskbar button labels are enabled.
; Is there a less obtrusive way to remove windows from the task switcher?

#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

WS_EX_APPWINDOW := 0x00040000
WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW := 0x00000080
WS_CHILD := 0x40000000

TempHiddenWindows := []
OriginalExStyles := Map()

!+`:: {
  FilteredWindowSwitcher()
}
!`:: {
  FilteredWindowSwitcher()
}
FilteredWindowSwitcher() {
  if TempHiddenWindows.Length {
    ; Needs #MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2 to handle Alt+`+`+`... to tab through windows with `, while waiting for Alt to be released
    ; Needs {Blind} to handle Alt+Shift+` to go in reverse
    Send "{Blind}{Tab}"
    return
  }
  try {
    ActiveProcessName := WinGetProcessName("A")
  } catch TargetError {
    MakeSplash("Window Switcher", "Active window not found.", 1000)
    return
  }
  WinClassCount := WinGetCount("ahk_exe " ActiveProcessName)
  if WinClassCount = 1 {
    return
  }
  WindowsOfApp := WinGetList("ahk_exe " ActiveProcessName)
  AllWindows := WinGetList()
  Messages := []
  for Window in AllWindows {
    SameApp := false
    for WindowOfApp in WindowsOfApp {
      if Window = WindowOfApp {
        SameApp := true
        break
      }
    }
    if !SameApp {
      if Switchable(Window) {
        try {
          ; MsgBox("Would hide:`n`n" DescribeWindow(Window), "Window Switcher")
          ExStyle := WinGetExStyle(Window)  ; redundantly accessed in Switchable...
          OriginalExStyles[Window] := ExStyle
          if WinGetClass(Window) = "ApplicationFrameWindow" {
            ; This is a Windows UWP app. It doesn't work to add WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW (though it doesn't generate an error).
            ; In fact, not even replacing all styles works:
            ; WinSetExStyle(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, Window)
            ; WinSetStyle(WS_CHILD, Window)
            ; WinHide doesn't work either, for UWP apps.
            ; It hides the window itself, but it doesn't hide it from the task switcher or the task bar.
            ; TODO: Find a way to hide UWP apps from the task switcher. This is pretty annoying!
            ; My only real idea is to move the window to a different virtual desktop,
            ; which would only work well with "Show all open windows when I press Alt+Tab" set to "Only on the desktop I'm using",
            ; and ideally with "On the taskbar, show all open windows" set to "On all desktops",
            ; which theoretically could avoid the taskbar animation, which could be nice for other windows as well.
            ; (These settings are in Multitasking in Settings.)
            ; No idea if it would be performant enough. There's a library for this though: https://github.com/FuPeiJiang/VD.ahk
            ; Perhaps that just speaks to the complexity of the solution though.
            ; It might be better to reimplement a task switcher from scratch at that point, though it would never look quite the same.
            ; WinHide(Window)
            ; Um, MakeSplash is no good here, since it blocks execution. But it's useful for debugging.
            ; MakeSplash("Window Switcher", "Hiding UWP app window: " WinGetTitle(Window), 1000)
            ; MakeSplash("Window Switcher", "Can't hide UWP app window from task switcher: " WinGetTitle(Window), 1000)
          } else {
            ; I have not seen any benefit to removing WS_EX_APPWINDOW, but I don't know if I've seen any windows with it.
            ; It may help in some cases, if I've done it right, but I don't know.
            WinSetExStyle(ExStyle | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW & ~WS_EX_APPWINDOW, Window)
          }
          TempHiddenWindows.Push(Window)
        } catch Error as e {
          ; It can get permission errors for certain windows, such as the Task Manager.
          ; But it's better to leave some extraneous windows in the list than to throw an error message up
          ; (especially while some windows are hidden, though I've made an array to delay the messages now.)

          ; Messages.Push("Error hiding window from the task switcher.`n`n" DescribeWindow(Window) "`n`n" e.Message)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  Send "{LAlt Down}"
  Send "{Blind}{Tab}" ; Tab or Shift+Tab to go in reverse
  KeyWait "LAlt"
  ; MakeSplash("Window Switcher", "Alt (physical key) released", 1000)
  for Window in TempHiddenWindows {
    ; If WinShow is ever used for a fallback, it should not be called for all windows, and it should be called at the end, so it doesn't slow things down for every window.
    ; WinShow(Window)

    ; Don't need to remember WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW state, since we're not matching windows with WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW.
    ; Restore WS_EX_APPWINDOW, if it was set.
    ; My first instinct was to allow other styles to change while hidden, as this may avoid problems with some apps,
    ; but styles may be forced to change as a result of WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW / removing WS_EX_APPWINDOW, I'm not sure.
    try {
      ; WinSetExStyle(WinGetExStyle(Window) & ~WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | (OriginalExStyles[Window] & WS_EX_APPWINDOW), Window)
      WinSetExStyle(OriginalExStyles[Window], Window)
      ; MsgBox("Would show:`n`n" DescribeWindow(Window), "Window Switcher")
    } catch Error as e {
      ; Delay error messages until after the switcher is closed and all windows are unhidden that can be.
      Messages.Push("Failed to unhide window from the task switcher.`n`n" DescribeWindow(Window) "`n`n" e.Message)
    }
  }
  TempHiddenWindows.Length := 0
  ; MakeSplash("Window Switcher", "Closing switcher (triggering logical release of Alt)", 1000)
  Send "{LAlt Up}" ; This could be earlier, couldn't it?
  ; MakeSplash("Window Switcher", "Switcher closed.", 1000)

  for message in Messages {
    MsgBox(message, "Window Switcher", 0x10)
  }
}

Switchable(Window) {
  ; Heuristics determine if a window is in the taskbar
  ; https://stackoverflow.com/a/2262791
  ExStyle := WinGetExStyle(Window)
  if ExStyle & WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW {
    return false
  }
  if ExStyle & WS_EX_APPWINDOW {
    return true
  }
  Style := WinGetStyle(Window)
  return !(Style & WS_CHILD)

  ; Not sure of the specific rules, or how much the priority of the cases matters.
  ; AI-autocompleted logic is slightly different:
  ; Style := WinGetStyle(Window)
  ; ExStyle := WinGetExStyle(Window)
  ; if Style & WS_CHILD {
  ;   return false
  ; }
  ; if ExStyle & WS_EX_APPWINDOW {
  ;   return true
  ; }
  ; if ExStyle & WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW {
  ;   return false
  ; }
  ; return true
}

DescribeWindow(Window) {
  return "Window Title: " WinGetTitle(Window) "`nWindow Class: " WinGetClass(Window) "`nProcess Name: " WinGetProcessName(Window)
}

;--------------------------------------------------------
; Win+Tab to switch between windows (TODO: between apps)
;--------------------------------------------------------

; #Tab::
; {
;   Send "{LAlt Down}{Tab}"
;   KeyWait "LWin"  ; Wait to release left Win key
;   Send "{LAlt Up}" ; Close switcher on hotkey release
; }
; return

;--------------------------------------------------------
; AUTO RELOAD THIS SCRIPT
;--------------------------------------------------------
~^s:: {
  if WinActive(A_ScriptName) {
    MakeSplash("AHK Auto-Reload", "`n  Reloading " A_ScriptName "  `n", 500)
    Reload
  }
}
MakeSplash(Title, Text, Duration := 0) {
  SplashGui := Gui(, Title)
  SplashGui.Opt("+AlwaysOnTop +Disabled -SysMenu +Owner")  ; +Owner avoids a taskbar button.
  SplashGui.Add("Text", , Text)
  SplashGui.Show("NoActivate")  ; NoActivate avoids deactivating the currently active window.
  if Duration {
    Sleep(Duration)
    SplashGui.Destroy()
  }
  return SplashGui
}
```