# For Mac, Automate Switching to Specific Chrome Tabs using Keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I have various Chrome tabs open that I use for my work flow.  They are all not on the same chrome window.

Screen 1:

- my daily work journal, Google Doc
- a scratchpad on Google Doc
- Github

Screen 2:

- Company internal tool 1
- Company internal tool 2

Screen 3:

- Company internal tool 3
- Company internal tool 4

Is there a way to set up to switch to these 7 (and possibly more) tabs using a keyboard shortcut?  Switching between the same tabs all day using my mouse is getting tedious.

I'm aware of Chrome's native CMD 1, CMD 2, etc but that is not what I'm trying to explain here.  They are not all open in a single Chrome window

Edit: by switching, here's what I mean.  When you are on Google Chrome, you can press CMD+SHIFT+A and search for the title (i.e. Daily Work Journal) of the tab - then press ENTER and it automatically takes you to tab so you know where it is.

Comment: Just to confirm what you're asking: you're trying to switch between tabs in multiple WINDOWS using keyboard shortcuts? I know Edge supports displaying each tab as a separate entity in Windows' Alt-Tab function. Does Chrome support this? This may be a pretty simple and "native" way to get this to work.

Comment: Also, have you looked at this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1604626/easy-way-to-switch-between-two-windows-of-the-same-app-in-windows-10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy way to switch between two windows of the same app in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1604626/easy-way-to-switch-between-two-windows-of-the-same-app-in-windows-10)

Comment: I've edited to include what "switching" means.  I'm trying to find a way to automate the user action of CMD+SHIFT+A , type in the title of the tab in the search bar, then press enter (all this when using Google Chrome)

Comment: Just to be clear, I am looking for something even faster than CMD+Tabbing.  I have 10 different apps open at the same time and tabbing through the list takes time.  I want to assign "Google Chrome: Daily Work Journal" to keyboard shortcut 1, "Google Chrome: Company Internal Tool 1" to keyboard shortcut 2, and so on, etc.  It's a pretty straightforward question I feel that I seem to not be getting across.  This is for Mac, not Windows.